# difficulty understanding different kinds of call statements

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

Considering the following kinds of CALL statements, I fail to understand the difference clearly.

```
CALL EAX
```

and

```
CALL DWORD PTR[EAX]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CALL EAX
```

Will call whatever address is in `eax`. If `eax` directly stores a function address, this is the right way.

```
CALL DWORD PTR[EAX]
```

Will first dereference whatever address is in `eax` and jump to the result of that. If `eax` stores a function pointer, this is the right way.

Answer (score 6):

The first form calls the function whose address is stored in eax.

The second calls the function whose address is stored at the memory location whose address in turn is stored in eax (that's simply one more level of indirection).

Comment: We can solve any problem by introducing an extra level of indirection - Butler Lampson

Answer (score 4):

```
CALL EAX
```

will take the value of EAX and jump to that value.

```
CALL DWORD PTR [EAX]
```

will take the value of EAX, and then dereference it(look it up in memory) and then call it.

so in C terms..

```
function_ptr=eax;
//v.s.
function_ptr=*eax;
```

or

```
(eax)();
//v.s.
(*eax)();
```